# Why does Spark application in Docker container fail with OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, docker

I'm using an r4.8xlarge on AWS Batch Service to run Spark. This is already a big machine, 32 vCPU, and 244 GB. On AWS Batch Service the process runs inside a Docker container. Out of multiple sources, I saw that we should use java with the parameters:

```
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1
```

Even with this parameters the process never when over 31Gb resident memory and 45 GB of virtual memory.

As analyzes I did:

```
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=1 -XshowSettings:vm -version
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 26.67G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

second test

```
docker run -it --rm 650967531325.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/java8_aws java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2 -XshowSettings:vm -version
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 26.67G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

third test

```
java -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=10 -XshowSettings:vm -version
VM settings:
    Max. Heap Size (Estimated): 11.38G
    Ergonomics Machine Class: server
    Using VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

openjdk version "1.8.0_151"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-8u151-b12-1~deb9u1-b12)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

The system is build with Native Packager as a standalone application. A `SparkSession` is built as follows with `Cores` equal to 31 (32-1):

```
SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName(applicationName)
  .master(s"local[$Cores]")
  .config("spark.executor.memory", "3g")
```

Answer to egorlitvinenko:

```
$ docker stats
CONTAINER ID        NAME                                                                    CPU %               MEM USAGE / LIMIT     MEM %               NET I/O             BLOCK I/O           PIDS
0c971993f830        ecs-marcos-BatchIntegration-DedupOrder-3-default-aab7fa93f0a6f1c86800   1946.34%            27.72GiB / 234.4GiB   11.83%              0B / 0B             72.9MB / 160kB      0
a5d6bf5522f6        ecs-agent                                                               0.19%               19.56MiB / 240.1GiB   0.01%               0B / 0B             25.7MB / 930kB      0
```

More tests, now with Oracle JDK, the memory never went over 4G:

```
$ 'spark-submit' '--class' 'integration.deduplication.DeduplicationApp' '--master' 'local[31]' '--executor-memory' '3G' '--driver-memory' '3G' '--conf' '-Xmx=150g' '/localName.jar' '--inPath' 's3a://dp-import-marcos-refined/platform-services/order/merged/*/*/*/*' '--outPath' 's3a://dp-import-marcos-refined/platform-services/order/deduplicated' '--jobName' 'DedupOrder' '--skuMappingPath' 's3a://dp-marcos-dwh/redshift/item_code_mapping'
```

I used the parameters `-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2` on my Spark, clearly not using all the memory. How can I go about this issue?

Comment: Where did you specify the memory of the driver? It's `1024M` by default. How do you submit the Spark app?

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr** Use `--driver-memory` and `--executor-memory` while `spark-submit` your Spark application or set the proper memory settings of the JVM that hosts the Spark application.

---

The memory for the driver is by default `1024M` which you can check out using `spark-submit`:

> **--driver-memory MEM** Memory for driver (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1024M).

The memory for the executor is by default `1G` which you can check out again using `spark-submit`:

> **--executor-memory MEM** Memory per executor (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G).

With that said, it does not really matter how much memory your execution environment has in total as a Spark application won't use more that the default `1G` for the driver and executors.

Since you use `local` master URL the memory settings of the driver's JVM are already set when you execute your Spark application. It is simply too late to set the memory settings while creating a `SparkSession`. The single JVM of the Spark application (with the driver and a single executor all running on the same JVM) has already been up and so no `config` can change it.

In other words, how much memory a Docker container has has no impact on how much memory the Spark application use. They are environments configured independently. Of course, the more memory a Docker container has the more a process inside could ever have (so they are indeed interconnected).

Use `--driver-memory` and `--executor-memory` while `spark-submit` your Spark application or set the proper memory settings of the JVM that hosts the Spark application.

Comment: I tryed:

'spark-submit' '--class' 'integration.deduplication.DeduplicationApp' '--master' 'local[31]' '--executor-memory' '3G' '--driver-memory' '3G' '--conf' 'spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap -XX:MaxRAMFraction=2' '/localName.jar' '--inPath' 's3a://dp-import-marcos-refined/platform-services/order/merged/*/*/*/*' '--outPath' 's3a://dp-import-marcos-refined/platform-services/order/deduplicated' '--jobName' 'DedupOrder' '--skuMappingPath' 's3a://dp-marcos-dwh/redshift/item_code_mapping'

Didn't solve the issue

Comment: The following should be without quotes around `3G` in `'--executor-memory' '3G' '--driver-memory' '3G'`.

Comment: `spark-submit --class integration.deduplication.DeduplicationApp --master local[31] --executor-memory 3G --driver-memory 3G --conf -Xmx=150g /localName.jar --inPath s3a://dp-import-marcos-refined/platform-services/order/merged/*/*/*/* --outPath s3a://dp-import-marcos-refined/platform-services/order/deduplicated --jobName DedupOrder --skuMappingPath s3a://dp-marcos-dwh/redshift/item_code_mapping}}` changed nothing :(

Comment: What do you mean by _"changed nothing"_? Can you check out the memory settings in the Environment tab of the Spark app?

Comment: Batch service don't provide port mapping :(

Comment: @oleber has the issue been resolved? I am having the same issue and wonder what is the solution. My understanding is to use   `spark-submit ... -executor-memory 3G ... --driver-memory 3G` rather than doing the `SparkSession.config(...)`, right?